# Factor analysis vs Bayesian Networks

Tags: factor-analysis, bayesian-network

My data is a very wide table with attributes, locations, behaviours, opinions of a set of users (distilled as summaries from many other tables).

My goals include:
(1) understanding the structure of my data set (what correlates with what? what are the latent factors?)
(2) making meaningful segments of users (likely based on these factors)
(3) prediction of certain columns

For handling (1), there seems to be a strong parallel between FA and BN:  they both provide for models in which items are influenced by unobserved or latent variables.

How would we characterise these two approaches, their pros and cons, and how would we choose between them?  Any pointers welcome.

My current understanding is:
- BNs inherently handle missing data well, not clear how to handle that with FA
- EFA allows determination of the number of latent factors
- BN structure learning allows automatic creation of structure using existing variables, but if you want to include latent variables in BN you need to do that manually
- BN makes prediction of items easy; I can imagine using factors to estimate missing items but I have not yet seen that method documented.  (It seems more correct to me to use PCA for prediction than rotated/simplified factors)
- I expect the structures found by both methods, may be somewhat related

Would it makes sense to use the two in concert?  Ie. use EFA to determine latent factors, then add those to the BN structure and proceed to estimate distributions in the BN.